# Spring boot spring-boot:run in eclipse does not kill background java process

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am running a spring boot web application through eclipse.

In eclipse, I have configured `spring-boot:run` maven goal. When run, the server starts up properly within the eclipse and I can invoke myactions.

When I want to stop the server, I just stop it by clicking on RED icon in Console window. The process seems to be stopped but server runs in the background and the java process can be seen as active in TaskManager.

Any idea, what could have been wrong ? Why the background process in not terminating ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved in Spring boot 3.0.0 release

Reference : [Bug link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32607)

Answer (score 1):

The Red Icon in Console window will just do a hard stop.

To enable graceful shutdown, install [Spring Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse) and run the app as a Spring boot App & enable the check Enable Life Cycle Management

This way, the application would gracefully shutdown when you stop from the console window

Comment: Thanks . I will try this out.