# Spring Boot App - Web server failed to start. Port 8092 was already in use

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When starting/relaunching a Spring Boot App and the app runs on a port which was already in use before I got an error:

```
Web server failed to start. Port 8092 was already in use.
```

So, everytime I am starting a Spring Boot App I have to switch `server.port` in `application.properties`.

Note: Because I do not have the Run as "Spring Boot App" I use the work around mentioned here to start it:
First Answer, [How to run Spring Boot web application in Eclipse itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677808/how-to-run-spring-boot-web-application-in-eclipse-itself)

Is there a solution to avoid switching ports every time?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need to switch ports every time you relaunch your application? If so that means the old instance is not killed properly.

Comment: Yes, I have to switch everytime... How could I kill it properly? I used the buttons "Terminate", "Remove Launch" and "Remove All Terminated Launches" but had no success so far.

Comment: When you terminate, ideally it should have terminated your previous instance and you should be able to launch the new instance on same instance (without changing the port in properties file)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643234/spring-boot-spring-bootrun-in-eclipse-does-not-kill-background-java-process

Comment: Go to command line and manually kill process using the related port

Comment: akuman8's answer helped. Thanks! It is solved.